# php change value of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I got a problem.

I make a function to update my config.json file.
The problem is, my config.json is a multdimensional array. To get a value of a key i use this function:

```
public function read($key)
{
    $read   = explode('.', $key);
    $config = $this->config;
    foreach ($read as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $config)) {
            $config = $config[$key];
        }
    }

    return $config;
}
```

I also made a function to update a key. But the problem is if i make `update('database.host', 'new value');` it dont updates only that key but it overrides the whole array.

This is my update function

```
public function update($key, $value)
{
    $read   = explode('.', $key);
    $config = $this->config;
        foreach ($read as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $config)) {
            if ($key === end($read)) {
                $config[$key] = $value;
                                     }
                $config = $config[$key];
                                              }
                                }
        print_r( $config );
}
```

my config.json looks like this:

```
{
    "database": {
        "host": "want to update with new value",
        "user": "root",
        "pass": "1234",
        "name": "dev"
    },
    some more content...
}
```

I have a working function but thats not really good. I know that the max of the indexes only can be three, so I count the exploded $key and update the value:

```
public function update($key, $value)
{
    $read  = explode('.', $key);
    $count = count($read);
        if ($count === 1) {
        $this->config[$read[0]] = $value;
    } elseif ($count === 2) {
        $this->config[$read[0]][$read[1]] = $value;
    } elseif ($count === 3) {
        $this->config[$read[0]][$read[1]][$read[3]] = $value;
    }
        print_r($this->config);
}
```

Just to know: the variable `$this->config` is my config.json parsed to an php array, so nothing wrong with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I had read your question better I now understand what you want, and your read function, though not very clear, works fine.

Your update can be improved though by using assign by reference `&` to loop over your indexes and assign the new value to the correct element of the array.

What the below code does is assign the complete config object to a temporary variable `newconfig` using call by reference, this means that whenever we change the `newconfig` variable we **also** change the `this->config` variable.
Using this "trick" multiple times we can in the end assign the new value to the `newconfig` variable and because of the call by reference assignments the correct element of the `this->config` object should be updated.

```
public function update($key, $value)
{
    $read  = explode('.', $key);
    $count = count($read);

    $newconfig = &$this->config; //assign a temp config variable to work with
    foreach($read as $key){
        //update the newconfig variable by reference to a part of the original object till we have the part of the config object we want to change.
        $newconfig = &$newconfig[$key];
    }
    $newconfig = $value;


    print_r($this->config);
}
```

Comment: This would work if i dont have a multidimensional array. Because i pass the string "database.host" so the function should update da value of `$this->config['database']['host']` but what your function is doing, is updateing the $this->config['database'] to the new value, that means it overrides the other subarray like host, user, pass. I hope you understand me, my english is not so good :s

Comment: You can use `is_array($value)` to check if the value is an array and call the function in a recursive way to solve the dimensionality problem you face.

Comment: Could you post an example? dont know exactly what you mean

Comment: @Rarely now I understand your question better, see my updated answer. That should improve your update code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
public function update($path, $value)
{
    array_replace_recursive(
        $this->config,
        $this->pathToArray("$path.$value")
    );

    var_dump($this->config);
}

protected function pathToArray($path)
{
    $pos = strpos($path, '.');
    if ($pos === false) {
        return $path;
    }

    $key = substr($path, 0, $pos);
    $path = substr($path, $pos + 1);

    return array(
        $key => $this->pathToArray($path),
    );
}
```

Please note that you can improve it to accept all data types for value, not only scalar ones

Comment: I wish I had this but in procedural, rather than object oriented programming.